# Phpmyadmin não salva arquivo se já tiver um salvo

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Fiz um código pra salvar o nome de um arquivo no banco de dados PhpMyAdimn, ele funciona se a tabela estiver vazia, porém quando vou tentar anexar outro arquivo ele da erro, alguém tem alguma ideia de porque isso ocorre?
Lembrando que o arquivo é salvo na pasta, apenas a parte do banco de dados que dá erro.

Aqui a conexão com o banco que usei:

```
<?php

class db {
    //host
    private $host = 'localhost';

//usuario
private $usuario = 'nome';

//senha
private $senha = '123456';

//banco de dados
private $database = 'banco';

public function conecta_mysql(){

    //criar a conexão
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->database);

    //ajustar a charser de cominicação entre a aplicação e o bd
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    //verificar se houve erro de conexão
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Erro ao tentar se conectar com o banco de dados'.mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $con;
}
}
?>
```

E esse é código php pra enviar e receber o arquivo:

```
  session_start();

  require_once('conecta.php');

  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {


    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['arquivo']['name']);

    $arq = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];

    $objDb = new db();
    $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
    $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('$email', '$arq')";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
      echo 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!';
    } else {
      echo 'Erro ao enviar o arquivo!';
    }

  } else {
    echo "Nenhum arquivo selecionado!";
  }

  $sel = "SELECT nomearq FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'";
  if (mysqli_query($link, $sel)){

    } else {
      echo 'Erro ao enviar o arquivo!';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Coloque isso, `echo mysqli_error($link);` antes do `echo 'Erro ao...`

Comment: Qual o erro? e qual a estrutura da sua tabela?

Comment: Só pra ter uma ideia, o nome do segundo arquivo que você tenta enviar tem nome diferente? Se tentar com arquivo de mesmo nome, ja tentou verificar se a tabela não está programada para impedir nomes iguais? Ou  tente também com e-mail diferente, para verificar se nao é o email que não pode se repetir.

Comment: @FernandoVR Desculpa a demora, tive uns problemas pessoais, eu coloquei o mysqli_error, mas não tem nenhum erro quanto à conexão, quanto à restrição, eu não coloquei nenhuma ainda, e também tentei com arquivos diferentes, continua o mesmo problema. Eu uso duas tabelas nesse banco, uma pra cadastro do usuário, ela funciona normalmente, e outro pra anexar arquivos, que é a que está dando esse problema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema, o que acontece é que eu tinha definido a variável e-mail como sendo primary key, por isso ele não aceitava o upload de outros arquivos!!!